# C++ Using different code to handle sorting of vector and list within the same program

Tags: c++, list, sorting, vector

I used `typedef vector<MyDatatype> ls;` to enable switching between list and vector by only changing the typedef definition. All works fine apart from sort function, which is implemented differently for vectors.

```
void show(driver& ls)
{
    ls.sort(compare); //this line gives error
    driver::iterator iter=ls.begin();
    int i=1;
    while(iter!=ls.end())
    {
        cout<<i<<". "<<iter->name<<string(maxlength+1-(iter->name).size(),' ');
        streamsize prec=cout.precision(2);
        cout<<grade(*iter);
        cout.precision(prec);
        cout<<endl;
        i++; iter++;
    }
}
```

Doing something like:

```
if(typeid(ls)==typeid(list<string>)) ls.sort(compare);
else if(typeid(ls)==typeid(vector<string>)) sort(ls.begin(), ls.end(), compare);
```

won't do any good. So my question is: is it at all possible to test for type and use suitable sort function accordingly, or do I have to write my own sort function (or maybe convert vector to list)? I couldn't find any related thread.

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to try to use typeid() to determine type at run time in order to make changes like you are describing.  There are times when it might be necessary but 99% of the time it is not.

Comment: @VaughnCato because `std::sort` needs random access http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach would be to use function overloading:

```
template <typename T, typename COMP>
void mySort(std::vector<T>& v, COMP c)
{
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), c);
}

template <typename T, typename COMP>
void mySort(std::list<T>& l, COMP c)
{
  l.sort(c);
}
```

Comment: Mankarse and juanchopanza, many thanks for really quick responses, wish I could vote you up, but my reputation does not allow for it yet.

Answer (score 5):

Use function overloads:

```
template<typename T, typename C>
void dosort(std::vector<T>& v, C compare) {
    std::sort(ls.begin(), ls.end(), compare);
}

template<typename T, typename C>
void dosort(std::list<T>& v, C compare) {
    ls.sort(compare);
}

void show(ls& list) {
    dosort(list);

    //...
}
```